# How can I replace one ViewController's fragment to another

Tags: swift, uikit

I need to show NoInternetConnectionView instead of UICollectionView when I don't have internet connection

Here is the image how View looks
[image]

Here is the image how it should look when I don't have internet connection

[image]

And here is the code of my ViewController

```
class GalleryViewController: UIViewController {
var presenter: ViewToPresenterPhotoProtocol?
var builder: GalleryRequestBuilder?
var service: APIService?


@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
private let footerView = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.large)
let reuseIdentifier = "customCVCell"
var isLoadingList: Bool = false
var collectionTitle: String?


@objc func refresh() {
    presenter?.refresh()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.titleLabel.text = collectionTitle
    collectionView.register(CollectionViewFooterView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "Footer")
    (collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.footerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 50)
    self.collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .valueChanged)
    presenter?.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (((scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height) > scrollView.contentSize.height ) && !isLoadingList && !presenter!.isEndReached){
        footerView.startAnimating()
        self.isLoadingList = true
        self.presenter?.fetchPhotos()
    }
}
}

extension GalleryViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.presenter?.photos.count ?? 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell
    
    cell.cellSetup(photo: (self.presenter?.photos[indexPath.item])!)
    
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 180, height: 128)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String,
                    at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter {
        let footer = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Footer", for: indexPath)
        footer.addSubview(footerView)
        footerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 50)
        return footer
    }
    return UICollectionReusableView()
    
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 20.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
                        collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 20.0
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
    if let destination = segue.destination as? PhotoDetailViewController,
       let index = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first {
        destination.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        destination.photo = self.presenter?.photos[index.row]
        
    }
    
}
}

extension GalleryViewController: PresenterToViewPhotoProtocol{
func onFetchPhotoSuccess() {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
    self.collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    self.collectionView!.layoutSubviews()
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    footerView.stopAnimating()
    self.isLoadingList = false
}

func onFetchPhotoFailure(error: String) {
    print("View receives the response from Presenter with error: \(error)")
    self.collectionView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NoInternetConnectionView", bundle: .main)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "NoInternetConnectionVC")
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    self.present(controller, animated: true)
}


}
```

As you see I've tried to call with present function but it's not what I need. So what is the best way to replace collection view on another view. Also I need an access to collection view's refresh indicator to reload data

Comment: use collectionView.backgroundView

Comment: I would recommend using [StatefulViewController](https://github.com/aschuch/StatefulViewController) or at least going through its implementation. It is a protocol based approach to solve this exact problem and then some.

Answer (score 0):

Add a object to represent your network state. You can add a listener to get changes in network state.

```
var isInternetAvailable : Bool = true
```

Now create a custom CollectionViewCell for your network error view and show that like the code below, so that refresh indicator will be still available

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   let count = isInternetAvailable ? self.presenter?.photos.count ?? 0 : 1
   return count }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
if isInternetAvailable {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell
    cell.cellSetup(photo: (self.presenter?.photos[indexPath.item])!)
    return cell
}else{
    // return your collectionview cell for network error
} }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
if isInternetAvailable {
    return CGSize(width: 180, height: 128)
}else{
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
} }
```